# hapi.js - How to redirect to originally requested route after successful authentication?

Tags: node.js, authentication, hapi.js

Is there something like `reply.redirect('back')` in hapi.js ? I am trying to redirect the user back to the original page they requested before they logged in successfully.

Answer (score 4):

When using the [hapi-auth-cookie](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi-auth-cookie) scheme, there's a handy setting for this exact purpose. Have a look at [`appendNext` in the options](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi-auth-cookie).

When you set this to `true`, the redirect to your login page will contain a query parameter `next`. `next` will be **equal to the request path of the original request**.

You can then use this on successful login to redirect to the desired page. Here's a runnable example that you can play with and modify to your needs:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');

var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 8080 });

server.register(require('hapi-auth-cookie'), function (err) {

    server.auth.strategy('session', 'cookie', {
        password: 'secret',
        cookie: 'sid-example',
        redirectTo: '/login',
        appendNext: true,      // adds a `next` query value
        isSecure: false
    });
});

server.route([
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/greetings',
        config: {
            auth: 'session',
            handler: function (request, reply) {

                reply('Hello there ' + request.auth.credentials.name);
            }
        }
    },
    {
        method: ['GET', 'POST'],
        path: '/login',
        config: {
            handler: function (request, reply) {

                if (request.method === 'post') {
                    request.auth.session.set({
                        name: 'John Doe'    // for example just let anyone authenticate
                    });

                    return reply.redirect(request.query.next); // perform redirect
                }

                reply('<html><head><title>Login page</title></head><body>' + 
                      '<form method="post"><input type="submit" value="login" /></form>' +
                      '</body></html>');
            },
            auth: {
                mode: 'try',
                strategy: 'session'
            },
            plugins: {
                'hapi-auth-cookie': {
                    redirectTo: false
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);

server.start(function (err) {

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    console.log('Server started!');
});
```

To test this out:

- Navigate to http://localhost:8080/greetings in a browser
- You'll be redirect to `/login`
- Click the login button
- Form posts to `/login` and then redirects to `/greetings` on success